# php, imap server username field

Tags: php, laravel, server, gmail, imap

I am trying to list e-mails using an php library in a laravel project found at this link: https://packagist.org/packages/ddeboer/imap. The library by itself is not a problem, since its object oriented and pretty fine to use.

When trying to make the imap server I am not able to make the conection because the username is invalid. I am using the following code. If its a email server, what username is requesting?

code:

```
<?php
    use Ddeboer\Imap\Server;

    $server = new Server('imap.gmail.com');

    // $connection is instance of \Ddeboer\Imap\Connection
    $connection = $server->authenticate('username', 'password');

    
/* // Run the method list which will return the list of messages 
    $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me');

    // Get the actual list 
    $messageList = $list->getMessages();

    // Create array where we will store our messages
    $messages = array();

    // iterate over all the elements retrieved by the method list
    foreach($messageList as $msg){

        // GET individual message
        $message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me',$msg->id);
        
        // Push the element into our array of messages
        array_push($messages,);
    }*/
$mailboxes = $connection->getMailboxes();

foreach ($mailboxes as $mailbox) {
    // Skip container-only mailboxes
    // @see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-getmailboxes.php
    if ($mailbox->getAttributes() & \LATT_NOSELECT) {
        continue;
    }

    // $mailbox is instance of \Ddeboer\Imap\Mailbox
    printf('Mailbox "%s" has %s messages', $mailbox->getName(), $mailbox->count());
}
?>
```

Comment: it asking for your client creds. for example if you have gmail account and you want to list it via the code that you shared - then you just simply need to provide your gmail user name (you@gmail.com) and password for that. 

If something doesnt work - check the guide of your email service provider - how to integrate IMAP

Comment: ´That is the thing, I am using gmail, and I have integrated/enabled Imap on gmail account, I am using my gmail and repective password. But it does not make the connection. With the following error:

[E_WARNING] Authentication failed for user "emailused@gmail.com": imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/validate-cert} imap_alerts (0): imap_errors (2): - [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) - Too many login failures

Comment: It looks like google is not allowing "not safe" apps to login, how can I make my laravel ap safe for that?

Comment: I guess you need to browse google-doc here - https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp 

My assumption that you need to enable API or it definitely has something to do inside of the google Eco-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going trough google info, I found out that less safe app options are not available anymore. So the solution I found is anabling two Factor authentication and use a app password generator. Use that password as password in the conection. And should work pretty fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).